# Awk output removes comma

Tags: awk

If I have the following csv file called mycsv.txt:

```
0123, fred, 012345, end
023, smith, 012, end
```

and apply this awk command:

```
awk '{$1=sprintf("%05d", $1);$3=sprintf("%08d", $3)}1' mycsv.txt
```

I get this output:

```
00123 fred, 00012345 end
00023 smith, 00000012 end
```

Why is the first and third comma removed and how do I make sure that they are included in the output.

Comment: Add `BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}`, your delimiter is a comma, but `awk` uses whitespace by default. Use `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {$1=sprintf("%05d", $1);$3=sprintf("%08d", $3)}1' mycsv.txt`

Comment: It's not `awk` removing the comma, but the `sprintf` that you used. `awk`gets `0123,` in `$1`, then you feed this to `sprintf`. It interprets that string as the number `123` (here you lost your comma) and writes it back in the format desired: `00123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things happening:

1. If you don't specify a field separator (e.g. `FS=","`) then awk will use chains of white space so then your first field, `$1`, of your first input line is `0123,` rather than `0123` and
2. When you perform a numeric operation on a string, awk strips all non-digits off the right side of that string and leading zeros off the left to turn it into a number so then `0123,` becomes `123` (and `000173foo` would become `173`).

So `$1` is `0123,` and therefore:

`sprintf("%05d", $1)` = `sprintf("%05d", "0123,")` = `sprintf("%05d", "123")` = `00123`

which when you assign that result to `$1` replaces `0123,` with `00123` hence the vanishing `,`.

This is what you really wanted:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"; OFS=", " }
    { $1=sprintf("%05d", $1); $3=sprintf("%08d", $3) }
1' mycsv.txt
```

The above will accept input with any white space around the field-separating `,`s and will ensure the output fields are all separated by exactly 1 comma followed by 1 blank. If you don't want the blanks in the output just change `OFS=", "` to `OFS=","`.

Answer (score 1):

The fields of the first line are `0123,`, `fred,`, `012345,` and `end`. You modified the first and third to `00123` and `00012345`, without a trailing comma. That's what awk prints.

You mean:

```
awk '{$1=sprintf("%05d,", $1);$3=sprintf("%08d,", $3)}1' mycsv.txt
```

Output:

```
00123, fred, 00012345, end
00023, smith, 00000012, end
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=", ";OFS=","} {$1=sprintf("%05d", $1);$3=sprintf("%08d", $3)}1' Input_file
```

Above will print output field separator as `,` in case you want to have `,` then set `OFS` as `OFS=", "`.

Output will be as follows.

```
00123,fred,00012345,end
00023,smith,00000012,end
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                        ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program from here.
  FS=", "                     ##Setting field separator as comma space here.
  OFS=","                     ##Setting OFS(output field separator) as comma here.
}
{
  $1=sprintf("%05d", $1)      ##Setting 1st field of value with sprintf value with 5 zeroes before 1st field value.
  $3=sprintf("%08d", $3)      ##Setting 3rd field of value with sprintf value with 5 zeroes before 3rd field value.
}
1                             ##Mentioning 1 will print current line here.
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```